# Allowing a window to be focused from Javascript in newest Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any way to allow .focus() on windows opened by "window.open" in the newest version of Google Chrome, like it is possible in Firefox, with the setting in about:config:

> dom.disable_window_flip = false

Example code:

```
const win = window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "_blank");
const win2 = window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");
win.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do it:

```
const win = window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "_blank");
win.focus();
```

Don't forget to allow popups (icon on the right side of the address bar).

Comment: The win.focus() has no effect. If the code was: "const win = window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "_blank"); const win2 = window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank"); win.focus();" it wont work